# How to make multiple HTML tables sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently using an open-source javascript table sorter: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/

The problem I have is that I dynamically add tables to my page in reaction to the user pressing a button. Only the most recently added table becomes sortable and the previous tables are not sortable anymore after I add the new table. Currently, I have this code at the end of my table creation:

```
 //Make table sortable
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#" + thisTable.ID).tablesorter();
        });
```

I don't understand why the old tables lose their sortability if they're not being reloaded. I am only appending a new table with a different ID under the previously added table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your selector to `$('table')`, and this will add the sorter to all tables. Your current code will only run on page load though, so you'll have to execute the `$('table').tablesorter();` line every time you dynamically add a new table (in your button's click handler).

It would be better though if you added a class, such as `sortedTable` to every table, and made your selector `$('.sortedTable')`, rather than simply `$('table')`, because you may at some time want a table that isn't sorted and the first version will always sort all tables. The second version will only sort those tables that you explicitly mark as sortable.